# apt-get command does not exists

Tags: apt, system-installation, system

Somehow `apt-get` disappeared, and it appears I have `dpkg`, or at least it doesn't fail 
with *command  not found*. I've tried software center, but  I don't know which app to load.
How can I load apt from scratch? I have the original Ubuntu 18.04 CD.

Comment: I've tried to get gdebi, but installation says to use apt-get,   which is a catch 22

Comment: Does `apt` on its own work?

Comment: No apt does not work 'error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.4.12

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you don't have Synaptic Package Manager either.

Download aptitude from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/apt)
and install with dpkg or gdebi

then

`sudo aptitude purge apt`

`sudo aptitude install apt`

also install synaptic for future use.

`sudo apt install synaptic`

Comment: Can't find apport-gtk

Comment: Now I get  dpkg: error processing package apport-gtk